# zero intensity in GLSL toon shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I have problem with intensity in toon shader. Value of intensity is always 0 but it shouldn´t be and I calculate it from vertex normal and light direction. I used this 
[reference card](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf).

```
vertexShader: 

varying vec2 vUv;
uniform vec3 ec_light_dir;
uniform mat3 normal_matrix;                   
varying float intensity;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
void main() {
    vec3 ec_normal = normalize(normal_matrix * a_normal);           
    intensity = dot(ec_light_dir,ec_normal);
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );}


fragmentShader: 

uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
varying vec2 vUv;

varying float intensity;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
    if (intensity > 0.95)   
        color = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.5,0.5);
    else if (intensity > 0.5)
        color = vec4(0.6,0.3,0.3,1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.25)
        color = vec4(0.4,0.2,0.2,1.0);
    else
        color = vec4(0.2,0.1,0.1,1.0);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Why is intensity always zero?

Comment: It might be negative. Try abs(...)

Comment: What OpenGL version are you using? This can't be the complete shader code, since you would have undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `ec_light_dir` is normalized and a_normal is not a zero vector. For this purpose, you can write their values (one per run) into `gl_FragColor` and look at the color drawn. Note: passing `ec_light_dir` through `normalize()` won't ensure it's normalized, as that function has undefined behavior if its arg was a zero vector in the first place.